# Angular JS $http.get()

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

For the below given code I'm not getting output

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mCtr">
    <p>{{content}}</p>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('mCtr',function($scope,$http)
    {
        $http.get("welcome.html").then(function(response)
        {
            $scope.content = response.data;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am getting output like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>AJS Services HTTP</title>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Welcome to world of AJS</p>
    <h1>AJS means Angular JS</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You get expected output. What do you want it to be?

Comment: _i'm not getting output_ a line later _I am getting output like this_... Hmm. So what is it?

Comment: Output should come show like this


Welcome to world of AJS
AJS means Angular JS

But it is appearing along with tags.

Comment: You're calling an html page, so you get the expected output. If you want only text you could try to call a txt file (maybe?) or a JSON like {greet: "Hello World"}.
Anyway remember that what you call from server come as is (except for any server-side script, like php scripts). So if you call an html page wirtten as you described in your question, it comes as you written it

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_http_get
plz see this example, here it is not showing the tags